# how can I make a multidimensional array with loop?

Tags: php, laravel, for-loop

I'm working on a Laravel/Livewire project and there is a table with these Datas:

attribute, value, price

I need to make an array with this data with for loop that return something like this:

```
`$property=[
  'attribute1'=>['value'=>'price','value2'=>'price2','...'=>'...'],
  'attribute2'=>['value'=>'price','value2'=>'price2', '...'=>'...'],
  '...'=>['...'=>'...'],

];`
```

for exp

```
$property= [
    'size'=>['x'=>'30000','xl'=>'35000'],
    'material'=>['wood'=>'55000','glass'=>'85000']
];
```

I try this but it returns wrong data

```
public $product,$key,$properties;


public function mount($id){
    $this->product=Product::with('attr')->findOrFail($id);
  
    $db=DB::table('attr_product')->where('product_id',$id)->get()->unique('attr_id')->count();


    for ($I=0; $I<$dB;$I++) {
        $attr_id=$this->product->attr[$i]->id;
        $attr=$this->product->attr[$i]->title;
        $value=$this->product->attr[$i]->pivot->value;
        $price=$this->product->attr[$i]->pivot->price;
        $pivotTableCount=DB::table('attr_product')->where('attr_id',$attr_id)->count();
        for ($j=0;$j<$pivotTableCount;$j++){
           $vp=array($value=>$price);
        }


        $this->properties[]=[$attr=>$vp];

    }
    

}
```

Comment: You want to return array like the format you shown on top?

Comment: yes @Sumitkumar

Comment: Mention the attr_product table and product_model

Comment: there is a Many To Many relations between products and attributes with pivot table that included  attr_id, product_id, value, price   but its not main point. the data can be anything  . the issues are loop and array which I want  @Sumitkumar

Answer (score 0):

```
$vp=array(
$attr=>
[ 
    $value => $price
 ]
);
```

Array format should be like this